# Not able to set the Backcolor of label as Transparent

Tags: vb.net

Using properties of "label" not able to set the backcolor as transparent ... when i select the color transparent from the option which is showing some color as backcolor, if transparent works properly must show background instead of some colors. please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a control at design time when setting the background to transparent it 'displays' the background of the form not the control on which it was placed unless that control is a container such as a panel.

2 options:

1 place the label on a panel and the label then displays the panel background (which can be a picture if that is what you are trying to do)

2 place the label programatically i.e.

```
dim Label1 As New Label
Control.Controls.Add(Label1)
Label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```